# Feynmf - two loop correction to 4 point function

Tags: feynmf

How can I draw the two loop correction to the four point function, with one of the loops on the right propagator?

I tried

```
\begin{fmffile}{loop}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,40)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
        \fmfright{o1,o2} 
        \fmf{plain}{i1,v1} 
        \fmf{plain}{i2,v2} 
        \fmf{plain,right=45}{v3,v3}
        \fmf{plain}{o1,v1}
        \fmf{plain}{o2,v2} 
        \fmf{plain,left}{v1,v2,v3,v1} 
    \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

which gave me

[image]

How can I make the internal loop a circle, and have the loop correction to the right propagator be rotated 90 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a proposal. It might be that there is an easier way, yet this way you have full control over the sizes of the loops. Let me also remark that `right=45` does not seem right. The number after the equality sign is not an angle, but a fraction, below I use `left=0.333`. And you probably know that you cannot compile the following with `pdflatex` without further ado, but compiling with `latex`,calling `mpost loop`, calling `latex` again and then converting to pdf works.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{loop}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,40)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
        \fmfright{o1,o2} 
        \fmf{plain}{i1,v1,o1} 
        \fmf{plain}{i2,v2,o2} 
        \fmf{plain,left}{v1,v2} 
      \fmffreeze    
         \fmf{phantom,left=0.33}{v2,v3,v1} 
      \fmffreeze    
         \fmfshift{10,0}{v3}
         \fmf{plain,left=0.33}{v2,v3,v1} 
         \fmf{phantom,left}{v3,v4,v3}
      \fmffreeze    
         \fmfshift{15,0}{v4}
         \fmf{plain,left}{v3,v4,v3}
    \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]